# Is it good practice to declare a mutable collection such as list in Enum?

Tags: java

The enum creates a list and a public method. The method is being called to add custom objects to the list. Is it a good design to have a mutable collection in Enum?

ex:-  SOURCE_MARKET_ORDER.createMergeDataByOrderType(hitValue, "ABC", "JKL");

// Enum Declartion

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public enum OrderDataType {
SOURCE_ENTITY_ORDER("EntityMaster Bulk Edit", "EntityMaster Merge Source", "EntityMergeSource", "source"),
TARGET_ENTITY_ORDER("EntityMaster Bulk Edit", "EntityMaster Merge Target", "EntityMergeTarget", "target"),
SOURCE_INSTRUMENT_ORDER("InstrumentMaster Bulk Edit", "InstrumentMaster Merge Source", "InstrumentMergeSource", "source"),
TARGET_INSTRUMENT_ORDER("InstrumentMaster Bulk Edit", "InstrumentMaster Merge Target", "InstrumentMergeTarget", "target"),
SOURCE_MARKET_ORDER("MarketMaster Bulk Edit", "MarketMaster Merge Source", "MarketMergeSource", "source"),
TARGET_MARKET_ORDER("MarketMaster Bulk Edit", "MarketMaster Merge Target", "MarketMergeTarget", "target"),
XREF_ORDER("CustomXRef", "Merge Custom XRef", "CustomXRef", "xref"),
;


private final String orderType;

private final String orderTypeName;

private final String componentName;

private final String type;

private final List<MergeData> mergeData = Lists.newArrayList();

OrderDataType(String orderType, String orderTypeName, String 
              componentName, String type) {

    this.orderType = orderType;
    this.orderTypeName = orderTypeName;
    this.componentName = componentName;
    this.type = type;

}

public String getOrderType() {
    return orderType;
}

public String getOrderTypeName() {
    return orderTypeName;
}

public String getComponentName() {
    return componentName;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public List<MergeData> getMergeData() {
    return mergeData;
}

void createMergeDataByOrderType(Map<String, String> hitValue, String 
dataProductId, String xmlDocument) {
    mergeData.add(new MergeData(dataProductId,
                                hitValue,
                                xmlDocument
    ));
}
```

}

Comment: You seem to abusing the intent of an enum. An enum is meant to be a relatively simple collection of named values known at compile-time. Having multiple fields, various methods, and mutable data is legal but not advisable when getting this complicated. Anyone else reading this code will be confused as to why you are treating an enum in this manner.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I felt the same and was looking for other experts' points of view.

Comment: (A) Tip: The [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature added in Java 16 might be of interest. Ditto the `List.of`/`Set.of` methods added to other recent versions of Java. (B) I’m not sure, but that merge-data should probably be kept elsewhere. Perhaps a multimap.